# jQuery append not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#modal').append('<input type="hidden" value="' + $('#selector').val() || myVar + '">');
```

What can cause my append above to not work? In the next line of it I do `append("test")` and it's working. There's no errors in my console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use brackets so the or operator only takes in to account the `$('#selector').val()`, not the `input` appended to it. Try this:

```
$('#modal').append('<input type="hidden" value="' + ($('#selector').val() || myVar) + '">');
```

Comment: Here's a helpful resource for Javascript order of operations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence As you can see || and && are below +, -, *, and /.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `input` and the value separately and then call append?

```
var inputValue = $('#selector').val() || myVar;
var $input = $("<input>", {"type": "hidden", "value": inputValue });
$('#modal').append($input);
```